# Create and deploy ListInstance without ListDefinition in a feature

Tags: 2013, list, visual-studio, feature

My feature should add some lists to a Sharepoint 2013 site. I have tried to add a list with ListDefinition and ListInstance to my project and only add the Instance to the feature which should be deployed, but it is not working.

When I only add a ListInstance to the project, I cannot customize and add Columns "the easy way with editor".

How can I add a ListInstance with my custom Columns without deploying a ListDefinition to the site with the feature?

I also dont want to write a huge punch of code for this problem, because I am going to add many lists in the feature with more features.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about features and list definitions for this! Instead, provision your site columns, site content types and lists with client-side code (CSOM/REST API). Use the [Office 365 Dev PnP Provisioning Engine](https://dev.office.com/blogs/introduction-to-office-365-dev-pnp-provisioning-engine) or the [Office Dev PnP PowerShell CmdLets](https://dev.office.com/blogs/introduction-to-office-365-dev-pnp-powershell) to provision SharePoint artifacts without having to code much yourself.

Alternatively, define your  columns and content types in the Content Type Hub and publish them. You can then easily create a new list and add the required content types(s). To have it as a list template in the UI; save a customized one as a template (.STP file) and upload it to the list gallery in all applicable sites.

Comment: But it is very fast and convenient to just add a feature and some lists and columns in the editor. Only dont want to have the definitions in my Sharepoint portal when you want to create new list from GUI.

Comment: You have added the same url in both links.

Comment: List definitions are only available with SharePoint on-premises. It's not possible with SharePoint Online. That's why I recommend not to consider list definitions anymore. But you can upload .stp files though! See this article on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/list-definition-template-sharepoint-add-in